# Error starting express server

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, npm

I'm getting an error when I try to start my express server and for the life of me I can't find out why. It was working for a while, and stopped working, but I don't know what I would have changed that would break it.

Here's the output:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.7.4
3 info using node@v0.12.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart mathlab@0.0.0
6 info start mathlab@0.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info mathlab@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: mathlab@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:213:16)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:14:12)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
10 verbose pkgid mathlab@0.0.0
11 verbose cwd /Users/alangm/Documents/localgit/mathlab
12 error Darwin 14.1.0
13 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
14 error node v0.12.2
15 error npm  v2.7.4
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error mathlab@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the mathlab@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the mathlab package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node ./bin/www
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls mathlab
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps:

a recent version of npm, probably 2.0, makes npm scripts throw errors if node is killed by something other than npm. I'm not sure if it happens when a child process is killed.

try adding this to your script:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function(){
  console.log('Detected kill signal');
  process.exit()
})
```

Comment: If you're not killing the process yourself, something else might be up. are you using `child_process.spawn` yourself? or is that just npm?

Comment: also, do you get failures running it without npm? `node ./bin/www`?